# Compiling errors in a program using threads

Tags: c, pthreads

On compiling I am getting an error "undefined reference to `pthread_create()`" and similarly for "undefined reference to `pthread_join()`". What are the possible reasons? I am unable to identify them.

Comment: the program first creates threads and den forks dem to create child and parent processes!

Comment: Add `-lpthread` to your compile command-line.

Comment: "Thread" is not a question, or even a sentence! And what's with all the dots? It's ridiculous!

Comment: Actually the title needs to have 15 characters and I was to lazy to think of a sentence....no offence TANDEM but I am sorry if dat hurt ur sentiments!

Comment: chinkychinky, if you're too lazy to think of a sentence, then most of us are too lazy to think of an answer.  You want good answers?  Ask good questions.

Comment: @abelenky......I am not Lazy......I was in a haste.I said ....M sorry!

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure you remembered the -lpthread flag in compilation? Usually that's the source of this error.

Answer (score 0):

You should add -pthread, which adds the required flags for the preprocessor as well as the linker. The flag suggested by others, -lpthread, only links the library, which may lead to the system libraries not having proper threading support.